# How can I change a custom keyboard key's background from a java class?

Tags: java, android, xml, keyboard, custom-keyboard

I'm developing an android keyboard and I need to change a key background when a specific key is pressed. I tried doing this into **mykeyboard.java** file:

```
private KeyboardView kv;
(...)
kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
keyboard = new Keyboard(this, qwerty);
kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
kv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        (...)

        (v.findViewById(R.id.myKeyId)).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
}
```

But this error happens:

> ᠎java.lang.NullPointerException:
>   Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference
>   at com.mtsolutions.mykeyboard.MyKeyBoard$1.onTouch(MyKeyBoard.java:87)

Which is this line:

```
(v.findViewById(R.id.myKeyId)).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

This is **res/layout/keyboard.xml** code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:keyPreviewHeight="0dp"/>
```

And where is some code from the **res/xml/qwerty.xml** file:

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="6.25%p"
    android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="0px"
    android:keyHeight="5%p">

    <Row>
        <Key> (...) android:id"@+id/myKeyId" (...) />
    </Row>

</Keyboard>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
kv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

instead of the complicated code, do this you